# ng-change borra input en angularjs

Tags: angularjs

tengo un problema que tengo un input

```
 <input    type="text"   id="tbusqueda" ng-model="Busqueda.texto"  placeholder="Estoy buscando"  ng-change="buscarPorDescripcion(Busqueda.texto)" >
```

esa función lo que hace es recibir el texto, ir a buscar a la BD, y traer  el listado y luego hago un ng-repeat y los muestro, el problema se presenta que cuando hago la busqueda se borra lo que escribi, osea escribo b, busca con la letra b, pero borra el valor del input, como hago para que no se borre?
La funcion hace esto

```
$scope.buscarPorDescripcion = function (val) {


        $scope.traerCampaniaPreciosBajos('t', 0, 0, 0,val);

}
```

esa funcion ba a buscar de la bd y me devuelve un array que despues recorro con ng-repeat.
Gracias

Comment: Hola, podrias incluir la porción de codigo del ng-repeat, ¿en algún lugar modificas el valor de val?

Comment: No sería mejor tener un botón y al momento de presionarlo que busque en la BD? Es antinatural que por cada letra que escribas en ese input busque en la BD... el rendimiento será pésimo en el futuro =/ . Existen alternativas para realizar lo que quieres colega =)

Comment: cjara, no no lo modifico, lo solucione declarando en el controller
$scope.Busqueda.texto = "Estoy buscando"; 
En cuanto a lo que dice paulo, si es verdad, lo habia pensado pero me lo requirieron asi, lo voy a consultar...gracias.